# EFCore failing to use DbSet naming convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using the latest efcore 2 preview from myget, it seems EF under certain conditions is not using the name of the `DbSet<>` property name as the table name. This is not exactly a simplified example...but this is the gist.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class  Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, I would expect the table generated to be called `Posts`... but instead it is using the singular version `Post` (the name of the entity).

There is no code inside the modelBuilder that is changing the pluralization or anything else that explicitly sets the table name.

Under what conditions would EFCore *not* default to using the `DbSet` property name as the table name? Has the default naming convention changed in efcore 2?

Comment: Default naming convention hasn't changed. EF Core will not use DbSet's name as EntityType is annotated with `Table` attribute or Fluent API is used to configure table's explicitly. If your EntityType is derived type then DbSet's name won't be used either since the data will be stored in BaseType's table whatever table name is configured for that.

Comment: The code you posted above works correctly and creates table Posts.